# why I am not able to query CollaborationGroupRecord in a trigger?

Tags: apex, chatter, chatter-groups

Any idea why I get "sObject type  CollaborationGroupRecord not supported" as compile error when I trying to query it in a trigger ?

I see that "Query()" is supported call in object description.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_CollaborationGroupRecord.htm

```
for(CollaborationGroupRecord CGR : [select id,CollaborationGroupId,RecordId from CollaborationGroupRecord  where RecordId IN : ObjFeedMap.keyset()]){

    if(!RecordRelatedGroups.containskey(CGR.RecordId ))
        RecordRelatedGroups.put(CGR.RecordId , new set<id>());

        RecordRelatedGroups.get(CGR.RecordId).add(CGR.CollaborationGroupId);

}
```

Interestingly same code works in a class but not in trigger. Trigger was on feeditem. Need to see if I call it from class what would happen.

Any help please?

Comment: Post your trigger code and/or the SOQL query you are using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"CollaborationGroupRecord requires a filter by a single Id, CollaborationGroupId or RecordId using the equals operator."

This SOQL will not execute because you cannot compare RecordId to the set of Ids returned by ObjFeedMap.keyset() even if that set only contains a single id

```
[select id,CollaborationGroupId,RecordId from CollaborationGroupRecord  where RecordId IN : ObjFeedMap.keyset()]
```

You will need to query a specific RecordId in your SOQL.

Comment: i agree @Developer Monk

Comment: I realised it . when it threw a run time error :). Thanks